# Linked List - Adding/Displaying using a vector

Tags: c++

I have a homework to do but I don't know what's the problem with the displaying function.. I have a vector use to make more linked list (it's a part of the homework).. that's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define MAX_LIST 100

struct nod {
    int info;
    nod* urm;
};

nod* liste[MAX_LIST];

void citesteListaSimpla(nod* liste[MAX_LIST],int nrListe);
void afisareListaSimpla(nod* liste[MAX_LIST],int nrListe);

int main()
{
    unsigned int nrListe;
    cout << "List numbers: ";
    cin>>nrListe;
    cout<<endl;
    citesteListaSimpla(liste,nrListe);
    afisareListaSimpla(liste,nrListe);
}

void citesteListaSimpla(nod* liste[MAX_LIST],int nrListe)
{
    for(int i=0; i<nrListe; i++)
    {
        unsigned int nrElemente;
        cout<<"Numbers of the list "<< i+1 << ": ";
        cin>>nrElemente;
        int element;
        liste[i]=NULL;
        nod* liste[nrListe];
        for(int j=1; j<=nrElemente; j++)
        {
            cout<<"Number "<<j<<": ";
            cin>>element;
            liste[nrListe]=new nod;
            liste[nrListe]->info=element;
            liste[nrListe]->urm=liste[i];
            liste[i]=liste[nrListe];
        }
    }
}

void afisareListaSimpla(nod* liste[MAX_LIST],int nrListe)
{
    for(int i=0; i<nrListe; i++)
    {
        nod* liste[nrListe];
        liste[nrListe]=liste[i];
        while(liste[nrListe]!=NULL)
        {
            cout<<liste[nrListe]->info<<", ";
            liste[nrListe]=liste[nrListe]->urm;
        }
    }
}
```

And if I run it it looks like this:
[image: console display]

How I make the program to show me the linked list ? ..

Comment: Compile it with warnings at level 4, then fix the problems it'll tell you about.  If there are still problems use a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 35 and 52 you're re-declaring `liste` shadowing the function parameter. Having `liste` declared in **three** different scopes is a recipe for disaster.

```
nod* liste[nrListe];
```

Removing those two lines seems to work.

You should probably use a better editor (I use CLion). You would have figured this out, because CLion warned me about it when I pasted your code in the editor. ;)

Comment: I feel so dumb right now :)) I spent some time in front of it and did not see that. Thank you very much mate and I will definitely try CLion.

Comment: Cool! Keep in mind that students can get a free license for Jetbrains products :)